# python selenium how to handle webpage randomly generates popups

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning how to scrap webpages and I got this issue with this website: [https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-sale~brossard?view=Thumbnail](https://www.centris.ca/en/properties%7Efor-sale%7Ebrossard?view=Thumbnail)

During the script execution, it would randomly give me a popup to subscribe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxPQ5.jpg

I already got the code to handle it, but it pops up at completely random intervals.

Like my current selection criteria would mean i have to scrap 41 pages, sometimes it is showing up at page 2, right before I click next page, sometimes it is showing up at 39, right as I am grabbing the price of a particular listing.

I can't just let the page sit there and wait, because I tried that and sometimes it doesn't show up for a solid 10 minutes and sometimes it shows at the 5min mark or 2min mark (since start of script).

If i visit the page manually, I get this issue way less often. I could click through all the listings and not get the pop up even once.

I am at a loss as to how to handle this.

```
import numpy as np
from Tools.scripts.dutree import display
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 

url = 'https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-sale~brossard?view=Thumbnail'


def scrap_pages(driver):
    listings = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'description')

    if listings[-1].text.split('/n')[0] == '': del listings[-1]

    for listing in listings:
        price=listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='price']/meta[@itemprop='price']").text
        mls = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@id='MlsNumberNoStealth']/p").text
        prop_type = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='location-container']/span[@itemprop='category']").text
        addr = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='location-container']/span[@class='address']").text
        city = addr.split('\n')[1]
        sector = addr.split('\n')[2]
        if prop_type == 'Land for sale' or prop_type == 'Lot for sale':
            bedrooms = 'NA'
            bathrooms = 'NA'
        else:
            bedrooms = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='cac']").text
            bathrooms = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='sdb']").text

        listing_item = {
            'mls':mls,
            'price': price,
            'Address': addr,
            'property Type': prop_type,
            'city': city,
            'bedrooms': bedrooms,
            'bathrooms': bathrooms,
            'sector': sector

        }

        centris_list.append(listing_item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    #chrome_options.add_argument("headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)


    centris_list=[]

    driver.get(url) 

    total_pages = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'pager-current').text.split('/')[1].strip() 
    
    for i in range(1,int(total_pages)):

        scrap_pages(driver)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.next> a').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='DialogInsightLightBoxCloseButton']")) > 0:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='DialogInsightLightBoxCloseButton']").click()
            time.sleep(0.6)
            print('found subscription box')
```

Comment: Because of that random popup, what is the error you've got?

Comment: Does that pop-up disturbing you getting information form currently presented page or just prevents you navigating to the next page?

Comment: @Prophet it does both...

Comment: depending on which part of script is executing when the pop up happens, it can be either can't find the next button, can't find price, stale DOM, can't interact with blabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to disable pop-ups in chrome but they are rarely work. You can search for disabling pop-ups with chrome options but i doubt anything will help.
I can just suggest more elegant solution:

```
scrap_pages(driver)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.next> a').click()
time.sleep(3)
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="DialogInsightLightBoxCloseButton"]').click()
    print('pop-up closed')
except (NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException):
    pass
```

for this to work you need to import error modules `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException`

Another option is to surrond the whole 'scrap page, click next' with a try block. But in that case you will need to catch another error: `ElementClickInterceptedException`. Code will look like this:

```
try:
    scrap_pages(driver)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.next> a').click()
except ElementClickInterceptedException as initial_error:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="DialogInsightLightBoxCloseButton"]').click()
        print('pop-up closed')
        scrap_pages(driver)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.next> a').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        raise initial_error
```

But you see that in that case you need to use same lines

```
scrap_pages(driver)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.next> a').click()
```

twice (in try and in except). Moreover, this pop-up can appear after you finally click the link and this will prevent correct scraping. It seems that the first option is better.

Comment: hmm maybe i could surrond the whole 'scrap page, click next' with a try block? try to click on the dialog, if fails, proceed?

Comment: I've added code for this option with some description to the answer. So I'd choose the first option.